# How can I ask somebody to unlock the askubuntu.com thread for more answers?

Tags: discussion

There is a thread "How do I show active dhcp leases"
The thread is locked by Eric Carvalho while ALL answers there are only partial.
I couldn't find a way to contact Eric personally (didn't find the inmail possibility).

I have spent 2 full workdays creating the working solution for the above problem mentioned in thread. Resulting Perl script is combining data from both log file and dhcpd.leases database and I would like to share it so that nobody else will have to repeat the whole process I went through.

The problem is not so uncommon.

Comment: Just create a new question and answer your own question.

Comment: I've asked for this post to be moved to meta so we can talk reopening.

Comment: What question are you talking about? Link?

Comment: The question link is: http://askubuntu.com/questions/219609/how-do-i-show-active-dhcp-leases

Answer (score 9):

I assume this is the question you are referring to: [How do I show active dhcp leases](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219609/how-do-i-show-active-dhcp-leases)

That question is not locked, it is just protected. This measure is to stop people from joining the site just to post "thanks" and spam as answers.

All you need to do is earn 10 reputations and you will be able to add your own answer. And since you currently have 21 reputation, you're good to go.

Comment: Even though I have 21 reputation points I cannot answer that question because the initial bonus does not count.

Comment: @MarcinGosiewski Which bonus? If you mean the "association bonus" that the message in that question mentions, then that doesn't apply to you. You should be able to answer that question now (The association bonus is a 100-reputation bonus you get when logging in to multiple [SE] sites, and having at least 200 reputation on any of those sites). What's the error you get now, if you try to answer the question?